# Angularjs show divs based on selections from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following in my angularjs app:

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in details">
     <td>{{ p.price | currency }}</td>
     <td ng-bind="{{ p.price }} * {{ p.quantity }} | currency"></td>
     <td>
          <select class="form-control">
              <option>Cash</option>
              <option>Cheque</option>
              <option>Debit</option>
              <option>Credit</option>
          </select>
     </td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, i will have multiple rows of results in the table. Based on a selection from the dropdown, i ll need to display appropriate divs one below the other.i.e. if i select `credit`, i want to display a div containing the fields required to enter the details like the *card number, expiry* etc. When i select `cheque` from my second result in the table, i would like to show a div for that as well below the previous div with fields like *cheque no*. etc.

So if i select both as `cheques`, i would like to show two divs with cheque fields.

What would be the best approach to this scenario? Any references and help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Have **an id** for the options and **show the div using ng-if** based on the values from the select box as below, I hope this is what you expected if not let me know the specifics of your need.

Also change the select menu as below ,

```
<select ng-model="optionSelected" ng-options="detail.id as detail.name for detail in details ">
```

Populate your details variable in controller,

```
  details = {["id":1,"name":"Cash"],["id":2,"name":"Cheque"],["id":2,"name":"Debit"] ...}

    <tr ng-repeat="p in details">
         <td>{{ p.price | currency }}</td>
         <td ng-bind="{{ p.price }} * {{ p.quantity }} | currency"></td>
         <td>
              <select ng-model="optionSelected" class="form-control">
                  <option>Cash</option>
                  <option>Cheque</option>
                  <option>Debit</option>
                  <option>Credit</option>
              </select>
         </td>
    </tr>

    <div ng-if="optionSelected==2">
           Cheque number stuff and other fields ..
    </div>
    <div ng-if="optionSelected==3">
          Card number stuff and other fields ..
    </div>
```

Comment: ok so what if i selected the same in both the dropdowns? I want a new div for the second selection as well

Answer (score 1):

If you bind values to the options and bind those to a model as in:

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" class="form-control">
          <option value="cash">Cash</option>
          <option value="checkque">Cheque</option>
          <option value="debit">Debit</option>
          <option value="credit">Credit</option>
  </select>
```

In this case you could make a div show up conditioned on `selectedOption` as follows:

```
<div ng-if="selectedOption==='credit'">
    <!-- this only shows up if you selected credit
</div>
```